# I need to make a program and require a upload file function in it, how do i do it?

Tags: python-3.x, file-upload, shutil, customtkinter

I am using customtkinter and shutil, I have made the basic functionality and the files are uploaded but only when I use Definite path, it does not work when I use a relative path
I want my program to work on any device, so obviously I can't use definite path. Is there any way I can bypass this? Like any module which can give me definite path in different computers so that I can use that or credentials which i can add in a f-string or another module which functions which relative path like shutil.

The code is something like this:

```
status=customtkinter.CTkLabel(master=Add_student,width=200,height=250,text="",image=uploadpending,font=("Poppins Regular", 24))
  
def upload_file():
    file_path = filedialog.askopenfilename()
    if file_path:
        try:
            shutil.copy2(file_path, uplpath)
            status.configure(image=Assetsuccess)
        except Exception as e:
            status.configure(text="Error uploading file: " + str(e),image=uploadfailed)
```

here if I put-

`uplpath="Uploads"`

then it shows that upload is successful but there isn't any file uploaded in the folder specified.

the file is only uploaded when I add a definite path like-

`uplpath="C:\\Users\\user\\Documents\\Coding files\\project\\Admin Window\\Uploads"`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the directory that the other file is in
in which case

`os.path.dirname(file_path)`

would give you the absolute path with respect to the other file.

then you could join it with `uplpath`

`os.path.join(os.path.dirname(file_path), uplpath)`

Comment: did not need to concatenate the two paths, was actually trying to get a absolute path from a relative path, but this worked too. I just added a dummy file and then used os.path.dirname() and got the absolute path for uploading. THANKS!!